# Rails server errors on windows computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm trying to install the Rails environment on my brother's computer so that we can collaborate on my app.

I think I've installed everything correctly, but now I'm running into major problems, I think because he's got a Windows computer. Basically, although everything is (I think) installed correctly, rails server won't run, because it produces the following errors:

It complains that there's a problem with

```
Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in 'require':
```

Then points to this file.

```
config/environments/development.rb:3: syntax error unexpected ':', expecting '}'
```

It also complains that that line has an

```
odd number list for Hash (SyntaxError)
```

That line is

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }
```

More importantly, that line works just fine on my Mac. The error goes away when I delete it. (But I don't want to delete it, and I especially don't want to delete the next one). Same with this error

```
Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in 'load':
```

of this line in my session_store initializer file:

```
<appname>::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_<appname>_session'
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Ruby 1.8.x but the `key: "value"` syntax is introduced in 1.9.x

```
{ host: "localhost:3000" }
```

Should be written as

```
{ :host => "localhost:3000" }
```